# How to push associative arrays to one 2D array

Tags: php, associative-array

How I can load two associative arrays into an index array through two separate functions like this:

```
 $allData =[];

 function func1(){
  $func1_arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
   array_push($allData, $func1_arr);
}
func1();

function func2(){
  $func2_arr = array('a' => 45, 'b' => 23, 'c' => 88, 'd' => 33, 'e' => 82);
array_push($allData, $func2_arr);
}
func2();

echo json_encode($allData);
```

I also tried passing the `$allData` as parameter of `func1($allData)` and `func2($allData)` but I am getting empty `[ ]` in return

```
$allData =[];

function func1($allData){
  $func1_arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
   array_push($allData, $func1_arr);
}
func1($allData);

function func2($allData){
  $func2_arr = array('a' => 45, 'b' => 23, 'c' => 88, 'd' => 33, 'e' => 82);
array_push($allData, $func2_arr);
}
func2($allData);

echo json_encode($allData);
```

### Update

Here is what I have tried with with `return`

```
$allData =[];

function func1($allData){
  $func1_arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
   return array_push($allData, $func1_arr);
}
func1($allData);

function func2($allData){
  $func2_arr = array('a' => 45, 'b' => 23, 'c' => 88, 'd' => 33, 'e' => 82);
 return array_push($allData, $func2_arr);
}
func2($allData);

echo json_encode($allData);
```

and still getting empty array in result

```
$allData =[];

function func1($allData){
  $func1_arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
    array_push($allData, $func1_arr);
    return $allData;
}
func1($allData);

function func2($allData){
  $func2_arr = array('a' => 45, 'b' => 23, 'c' => 88, 'd' => 33, 'e' => 82);
  array_push($allData, $func2_arr);
  return $allData;
}
func2($allData);

echo json_encode($allData);
```

Comment: What do you expect the final array to look like?

Comment: You really need to learn about variable scope: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/3933332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it myself ,I just do not know why some genius! are voting down my question

```
$allData =[];

function func1(){
global $allData;
  $func1_arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
   array_push($allData, $func1_arr);
}
func1();

function func2(){
global $allData;
  $func2_arr = array('a' => 45, 'b' => 23, 'c' => 88, 'd' => 33, 'e' => 82);
array_push($allData, $func2_arr);
}
func2();

echo json_encode($allData);
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use `global` especially if you don't have to. **return** your data, which you first pass to the function!

Comment: so what is the solution?! what do you mean by `return your data, which you first pass to the function!` thanks

Comment: I guess you still didn't read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659626/how-to-push-associate-arrays-to-one-2d-array/32659840?noredirect=1#comment53165809_32659626

Comment: I read it that's why I pass the `$allData` through function parameters but it didnt work!

Comment: I also tried the `function func2() use ($allData){}` but getting this error `syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting `

Comment: and about the `return` I am not sure what should I here?! as i said I am uploading an array into another array what should I return here?!

Comment: Please take a look at update part of question, I tried all of options at the page you referenced!

Comment: Your last attempt in your question is getting really close. You now only need to assign the return value of the functions to the array again.

Comment: `You now only need to assign the return value of the functions to the array `  you mean in functions or outside?

Comment: `$allData = func2($allData);` and the same for the first function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90068/discussion-between-rizier123-and-mona-coder).